# Connect with .net core to SSAS

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ssas, .net-core

I'm trying to connect Microsoft SQL Server Analysis server ( SSAS ) from .net core. At first I tried using `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient`, but it's not compatible with .net core.

Is there a way to reach SSAS and fetch some data in any other way using .net core?

Answer (score 3):

After a while, we couldn't do it with .net core. So, I've created a proxy with .net 4.6, which is reachable for main project as REST WS. This proxy uses `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient` just fine.